# My sprinkles do not land on the donut and stick

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine

Hello so I am wondering how to make these sprinkle-cylinder objects collide and stick to a donut. However, some fly away, some fall through the donut, and only a relative few actually stay on the donut.

[image: Donut with sprinkles hovering over]

I generated the sprinkles by copying a cylinder object and then spinning them around a central point, then randomizing their rotate transformations. They all have a rigid body and collide modifier, and the donut has a collide modifier. Both collide modifiers have their collision surface set to "mesh", so I do not know what else could be causing this unwanted behavior.

[image: Sprinkle Modifier]
[image: Donut Modifier 1]
[image: Donut Modifier 2]

I have messed with the friction of the rigid body modifier to no avail.

*How do I make the sprinkles fall down in the animation tab and stick onto the top donut face  exactly without approximating the top as a square face?*

[image: Whole project]

Comment: hello please share your file: https://blend-exchange.com/

Comment: collide modifier has nothing to do with rigid body simulation. Rigid bodies collide only with rigid bodies. So either give the donut rigid body (maybe passive). But for sure you can delete the collide modifiers. Collide is for soft body, particles and cloth.